# Find/Replace Inside Texareas WYSIWYG

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, tinymce, wysiwyg

I believe the problem with finding/replacing text is when a wysiwyg steps into the mix.
However, I'm sure someone has figured out how to do the magic.

Here's the textarea, with no editor attached:

```
<textarea id="template1" style="width:400px; height:200px;">
<div>Dear {{companyname}},</div>
<div>A new Support Case has been opened for you.</div>
<div>Support Case description:</div>
.........more html text follows
</textarea>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

   var str = $("#template1").val();
   var newstr = str.replace("{{companyname}}", "ACME Inc");
   $("#template1").val(newstr);

}); 
</script>
```

Without the editor, I'm good to go.
As soon as I apply my editor of choice (TinyMCE), the replace() method gets ignored.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Just a thought, maybe TinyMCE replaces the curly brackets with their respective ISO code, that's worth looking into.

Comment: tinyMCE is replacing the textarea by an iframe. i suppose they offer ways to access the content/set some callback. but did you try instantiating your editor after making the replace ?

Comment: Every wysiwyg that I know will use the textarea's content as a starting place, but once initialized they more/less ignore it and point to the editable region that the library creates/inserts. Check out their API for any methods that are exposed for searching/replacing within a given instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons why your replace function doesn't work.

**1.** The contents of the former textarea get replaced, but you cannot see the result because tinymce hides the textarea and uses a contenteditable iframe to load and style the former contents. The editor content gets written back to the textarea onSave and onSubmit

**2.** `$(document).ready` all ressources of your page have been loaded, but the tinymce editor is not ready.

This will lead to the question on how to replace the code in the tinymce editor. `$(document).ready` won't help here. You will need use the tinymce configuration paramter [onInit](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onInit)

```
// Adds an observer to the onInit event using tinyMCE.init

tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
          //console.debug('Editor is done: ' + ed.id);

          // replace the editor content
          var str = ed.getContent();
          var newstr = str.replace("{{companyname}}", "ACME Inc");
          ed.setContent(newstr);
      });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the actual Html generated by tinymce in your favourite page inspector (firebug, dev tools, dragonfly etc), you will see that you are actually editing an iframe with contentEditable enabled. As far as i can tell it will use the textarea/input to set the initial content, and do some other sort of voodoo to set it back when you post the form back to the server.

If you want to do it manually there are methods to do so:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.setContent

You could do your text processing via those.